# Unacceptable TLS certificate Pulse secure

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to connect to the VPN of the work using Ubuntu 18.04 and Pulse Secure and I had this error:

Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL https://vpn.imppc.org/

Unacceptable TLS certificate

Comment: can't tell exactly what the issue is, but I'm in the middle of a similar issue. These KB articles look relevant:
https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB43927
https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB40278